# Is there any restrictions available for file uploadings?

Tags: php, uploading

I'm learning PHP course.In that now I'm learning the file uploading concept.

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple">
```

We can do the file uploading. But I had one doubt. Is there any restrictions here for uploading the different file types. Which means can we upload any  file through the uploading or is there any restrictions here?

Comment: The thing is - you can never rely on any restrictions made on the client side. Everything that your server receives should be treated as a malicious attempt to fool you.

Comment: yeah ,I understand thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are no restrictions in to the type of file you can upload. But you can set various limits regarding the file uploads in `php.ini` file.

These are examples

```
memory_limit = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 24M
post_max_size = 32M
```

[Here](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204404784/how-do-i-increase-the-php-upload-limits) is a useful article about these limits.

And [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) is your best reference about file uploading in PHP.

Answer (score -1):

In HTML5 you can add the multiple attribute to select more than 1 file.You can upload any type of file provided in your php.ini file  **file_uploads = On**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="my_file[]" multiple>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </form>
```

Also to know more about **enctype="multipart/form-data"**

[What does enctype='multipart/form-data' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)